# ActiveMQ Data persistent Issue in Java Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, activemq-classic

I have an application which uses embedded activeMQ 5.11. At the start of the application it creates activemq-data\producerBroker\KahaDB folder at the class path location. I do want to change the location but spring.xml doesn't take a location.

Spring.xml as given,

```
<bean id="producerBroker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.SslBrokerService">
    <property name="brokerName" value="producerBroker" />
    <property name="persistent" value="true" />
     <property name="persistenceAdapter" ref="persistenceAdapter"/>
    <property name="transportConnectors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector">
                <property name="name" value="xxx"></property>
                <property name="uri" value="${transportConnectorURIs}"></property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jmsBridgeConnectors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.JmsQueueConnector">
                <property name="outboundQueueConnectionFactory">
                    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
                        <property name="brokerURL" value="${brokerURL}" />
                        <property name="userName" value="${username}" />
                        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
                        <property name="trustStore" value="${trust.store.path}" />
                        <property name="trustStorePassword" value="${trust.store.password}" />
                        <!-- <property name="keyStore" value="${key.store.path}"/> -->
                        <!-- <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${key.store.password}"/> -->
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="outboundQueueBridges">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge">
                            <constructor-arg value="${screenshotQueueName}" />
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.network.jms.OutboundQueueBridge">
                            <constructor-arg value="${resultXmlQueueName}" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>

            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="persistenceAdapter" class="org.apache.activemq.store.kahadaptor.KahaPersistenceAdapter">
<property name="directory" value="E:\test"/>
```

Current issue is it throws an error as "exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.activemq.store.kahadaptor.KahaPersistenceA
apter] for bean with name 'kahaPersistenceAdapter' defined in class path resource [spring/resultupload/resultupload.xml]; nested exception is java.la
g.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.store.kahadaptor.KahaPersistenceAdapter"

Anyone has experience in the directory change in activeMQ 5.11 in java spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination of the persistence location must be defined at the broker level.

The [kahaPersistenceAdapter](http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.8.0-schema.html#kahaPersistenceAdapter) (which was file based) was removed with version 5.9. You should use the kahaDB.

kahaDB - uses KahaDB an embedded lightweight non-relational database

```
<broker brokerName="broker" persistent="true" useShutdownHook="false">
   <transportConnectors>
     <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
   </transportConnectors>
   <persistenceAdapter>
     <kahaDB directory="e:/temp" ... />
   </persistenceAdapter>
 </broker>
```

all valid attributes: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.11.0-schema.html#kahaDB

Comment: Thanks alot. I was able to get it work with the given information.